# error retrieving data from an object array swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to code a message chat log between users. so I want to retrieve only specific data from my message array. For example when a person sends a text message I only want to retrieve from my message array fromId,toId, and text. when a person sends an image I want to only retrieve fromId,toId and imageUrl. At the moment the app crashes because when a person sends a text "imageUrl" is nil and vice versa sending an image where "text" is nil. Is there a way around this? Or do I have to create 2 separate arrays? Thanks in advance

message array

```
class Message {

    var fromId: String
    var text: String
    var toId: String
    var timeStamp: NSNumber?
    var imageUrl: String



    init(fromId: String, text: String, toId: String, timeStamp: NSNumber, imageUrl: String){


        self.fromId = fromId
        self.text = text
        self.toId = toId
        self.imageUrl = imageUrl

    }

    init(snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) {

        self.fromId = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["fromId"] as! String!

        self.toId = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["toId"] as! String!

        self.text = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["text"] as! String!

        self.imageUrl = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["imageUrl"] as! String!


    }
```

firebase structure

```
{ "messages": {

"KkGAWnQhqnOx525vv2W": {

"fromId": tvyT6UF6mWZeewAJXt076qqt7ek2,
"toId": USk3w8ZPYlRhfDmEwWwtkMhzUNX2,
"text": "Hello"
},
"hujU6UF6mWZeewAJXt0": {

"fromId": tvyT6UF6mWZeewAJXt076qqt7ek2,
"toId": USk3w8ZPYlRhfDmEwWwtkMhzUNX2,
"imageUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b.."
}
```

method used to retrieve data

```
var message = [Message]()

func observeMessages(){

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(uid)

    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in


        let messageId = snapshot.key

        let messageReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages").child(messageId)
        messageReference.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in


            for posts in snapshot.children{

                let message = Message(snapshot: posts as! FIRDataSnapshot )

                let chatPartnerId = message.chatPartnerId()

                self.messagesDictionary[chatPartnerId!] = message


                    self.messageTableView.reloadData()
                })
            }

    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

Comment: Use optionals instead of force unwrapping the data.

Comment: Hi @JohnMontgomery thanks for your reply. could you elaborate more on your answer please

Comment: You say the text and URL are sometimes nil.  That means they will crash when you use `!` to force unwrap them.  You need to not do that and make the properties `String?`s instead.

Comment: @j.iese Check my below solution for that also it is batter if you add one more key in your message object as I suggested in my solution

Comment: @NiravD ok I am trying it out now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is crashing is because you are forcefully wrapping value when you subscript with dictionary. You need to use `if let` or `guard let` to wrapped the optional or you can use `Nil-Coalescing Operator` with default value empty and later check which one is non empty `text` or `image`.

```
init(snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) {
    let dictionary = snapshot.value as! [String:Any]
    self.fromId = dictionary["fromId"] as! String
    self.toId = dictionary["toId"] as! String
    self.text = dictionary["text"] as? String ?? ""
    self.imageUrl = dictionary["imageUrl"] as? String ?? ""
}
```

Also the batter option is to add one more key with your message object as `type` and with value either `text` or `image`. Make your structure like this.

```
{
    "messages": {

        "KkGAWnQhqnOx525vv2W": {
            "fromId": tvyT6UF6mWZeewAJXt076qqt7ek2,
            "toId": USk3w8ZPYlRhfDmEwWwtkMhzUNX2,
            "type" "text"
            "text": "Hello"
        },
        "hujU6UF6mWZeewAJXt0": {

            "fromId": tvyT6UF6mWZeewAJXt076qqt7ek2,
            "toId": USk3w8ZPYlRhfDmEwWwtkMhzUNX2,
            "type" "image"
            "imageUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b.."
        }
    }
}
```

After that get the value of type and compare is it `text` or `image`

```
init(snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) {
    let dictionary = snapshot.value as! [String:Any]
    self.fromId = dictionary["fromId"] as! String
    self.toId = dictionary["toId"] as! String
    //Make one more property with name type of String
    self.type = dictionary["type"] as! String
    self.text = dictionary["text"] as? String ?? ""
    self.imageUrl = dictionary["imageUrl"] as? String ?? ""
}
```

Now when you access this object check its type and access its property text and imageUrl according to it.

Comment: ok thank you so much it worked. Now with adding type to the array how would I check its type and access its property?

Comment: @j.iese Welcome mate :) Simply check `if (object.type == "text") {//access text property } else { //access imageUrl property }`

Comment: @j.iese Welcome mate :)